# Jekyll URLs add leading slash when pushed to Github Pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I have successfully hosted on Github Pages. Today I was trying to run the site through browser-sync so I could view my changes faster, and noticed that my urls were different when served locally than on the actual website. Here's what the local url looks like:

```
<a href="blog/post-title/">
```

Which when clicked on brings me to the page

```
http://localhost:3000/blog/blog/oven-baked-fajitas/
```

This same link, once it has been pushed to the Github repo and processed by them, turns into

```
<a href="/blog/blog-title/">
```

Which works correctly.

I link to individual posts in my archive like this:

```
<a href="{{ post.url }}">
```

And my `_config.yml` is as follows:

```
name: Adam Hammes
description: Adam Hammes' Website
author: Adam Hammes
url: http://hammes.io
permalink: blog/:title/
excerpt_separator: <!--more-->
exclude: ["README.md", "gulpfile.js", "package.json", "node_modules"]
```

What I have tried:

1. I added `baseurl: ""` to my `_config.yml`; no effect.
2. I added `baseurl: "/"`; no effect.
3. I added `baseurl: "/"`, and changed the link format to `{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url}}`; this fixed the links locally, but resulted in 2 leading slashes live thus breaking the links.

Answer (score 0):

I was using an old version of Ruby. By updating to Ruby 2 and then running `gem install Jekyll` I was able to get consistent behavior.